# silverlight installation

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I already installed Blend_Trial_en.exe, Silverlight3_Tools.exe, Silverlight 3 Toolkit November 2009.msi.
But my browser asking for silverlight plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link included in that prompt, you should click it.

Silverlight 3 is also reasonably old now, you may want to consider installing the Silverligh 4 versions of the Tools and Tool Kit.